# Remote access to a mysql on ZYXEL NAS

Tags: ssh, mysql, nas, remote-access

I have bought a [Zyxel NAS 326](http://www.zyxel.it/Prodotti/Scheda/NAS326-EU0101F) and now I'm having problems accessing MySQL from a machine that is not the localhost.

MySQL was installed through php-mysql-phpmyadmin APP (the only one with MySQL) and I don't know how to change MySQL config to bind access.

From SSH I can't find my.cnf file.

How can I modify the configuration of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the following 4 files from "127.0.0.1" to "0.0.0.0"

/usr/local/mysql/bin/reset_zyadmin 
- Line:25:./bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-table --bind-address=127.0.0.1 &

/usr/local/mysql/bin/reset_zyadmin 
- Line:65:./bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --bind-address=127.0.0.1 &

/usr/local/mysql/bin/reset 
- Line:38:./bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --bind-address=127.0.0.1 &

/usr/local/mysql/bin/init 
- Line:13:./bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-table --bind-address=127.0.0.1 &

Then login to zyxel admin page select app PHP-MySQL-phpMyAdmin and press "Reset MySQL Database Password"
Remark : after you reset password to default it will create the bind-address value as "0.0.0.0" now you're able to login MySQL remotely (Note : MySQL user must set as any host as well)
enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

***In addition*** to Ek's solution I found a mod which makes Zyxel boots with mysql remote access available permanently.
https://homeforum.zyxel.com/discussion/1926/the-mysql-server-of-the-nas326-app-runs-only-on-localhost-how-do-i-make-it-lan-reachable
"nintendoeats" figured out:
"SSH into your NAS, and use vi to edit the following file:
/i-data/longAlphanumeric/.PKG/PHP-MySQL-phpMyAdmin/etc/init.d/PHP-MySQL-phpMyAdmin

You need to make 2 changes:

```
ln the chckmd5sum() function, change return 2 to continue (this bypasses the md5 check). This is at line 31.
In the enable() function, find the line with --bind-address=127.0.0.1 and change it to the NAS'es static IP. This is at line 61.
```

Save, restart your NAS, have a party."
Of course, All would prefer 0.0.0.0 instead of a static IP.